# Magento 2.4.6 - Getting Error Could not validate a connection to OpenSearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.6, opensearch

I am getting below error while installing Magento 2.4.6 using command line.

Could not validate a connection to OpenSearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster

[image]

I have run below two commands

```
META_PACKAGE=magento/project-community-edition META_VERSION=2.4.x

 composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ \
     "${META_PACKAGE}" /tmp/exampleproject "${META_VERSION}"

 rsync -a /tmp/exampleproject/ /var/www/html/
 rm -rf /tmp/exampleproject/
```

and this

```
bin/magento setup:install \
     --backend-frontname=backend \
     --amqp-host=rabbitmq \
     --amqp-port=5672 \
     --amqp-user=guest \
     --amqp-password=guest \
     --db-host=db \
     --db-name=magento \
     --db-user=magento \
     --db-password=magento \
     --search-engine=opensearch \
     --opensearch-host=opensearch \
     --opensearch-port=9200 \
     --opensearch-index-prefix=magento2 \
     --opensearch-enable-auth=0 \
     --opensearch-timeout=15 \
     --http-cache-hosts=varnish:80 \
     --session-save=redis \
     --session-save-redis-host=redis \
     --session-save-redis-port=6379 \
     --session-save-redis-db=2 \
     --session-save-redis-max-concurrency=20 \
     --cache-backend=redis \
     --cache-backend-redis-server=redis \
     --cache-backend-redis-db=0 \
     --cache-backend-redis-port=6379 \
     --page-cache=redis \
     --page-cache-redis-server=redis \
     --page-cache-redis-db=1 \
     --page-cache-redis-port=6379
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this one `--search-engine= elasticsearch7` instead of this `--search-engine=opensearch`

I think it will solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

**Establish a connection with the elastic search during setup install**

```
--search-engine=elasticsearch7 

 --elasticsearch-host= hostname 

 --elasticsearch-port= port number

 --elasticsearch-index-prefix= magento

 --elasticsearch-timeout=15
```